# Is it possible to store Views in database using ASP.NET 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, roslyn

I would like to store View files in database and provide a dynamic compilation (in memory) functionality (For portability and multi-tenancy reasons).

Is it possible to serve Views from Database instead of physical files?
I need to add that I am interested to support this on a certain folder not the entire Views folder.

Alternatively, If I would to be able to compile the certain Views into in-memory assemblies (not sure if Roslyn now allows the Views also to be compiled into .NET assembly) and then somehow allow the MVC Razor Engine access them I would achieve the same results.